# How to use a variable for method calls in a ruby object?

Tags: ruby, variables, interpolation

I have an array of anonymous hashes which I use to define a configuration to be printed out as output. Each anonymous hash has a label and a field as keys along with their corresponding values.

In Perl, I would do something like below:

```
foreach my $config ( @configurations )
{
    foreach my $element ( keys %{$configuration} )
    {
        print $element . " - " . $config->{$element} . "\n";
    }
}
```

Observe the use of the variable, `$element` above which represents the keys (ie. label and field).

I would like to do the same in ruby but I found that `#{variable-name}` does not work when I try to use that against a Ruby object.

How do I go about using a variable as method calls to a Ruby object?

Answer (score 4):

I believe you mean this:

```
my_hash.each do |key, value| 
  puts "#{key} - #{value}"
end
```

In ruby this is called a `block`. It makes a call to a inner function and passes some variables to be used inside its scope. 
Like the documentation says:

> Calls block once for each key in hsh, passing the key-value pair as parameters.
>   http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Hash.html#method-i-each